# Sort list of lists by expression in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I'd like to sort a list of lists by some expression in Python.

I.e., sort list of lists by the value of `abs(x[0] - x[3])`, where `x` is a sublist. I can do it by appending another element to the lists, sorting by it and removing it, but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass it as the key function to sort:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[3]))
```

For example:

```
In [1]: my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 7], [4, 6]]

In [2]: my_list.sort(key=lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]))

In [3]: my_list
Out[3]: [[1, 2], [4, 6], [3, 7]]
```